# Google maps opening on Android but not IOS

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, google-api

I have a gesture Detector that contains a GoogleMap widget that when click opens the google maps app (I also tried in browser), this work on both an android emulator and physical device but not on iOS emulator or physical device. The map still show as well as the but and you can interact with it(zoom in and out) but clicking does nothing. I have set everything up correctly and have no restrictions on the API, what could be causing this?

Source code:

```
  //Google Maps
  final Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller =
      Completer<GoogleMapController>();

  static const CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(51.917405387278585, -8.397318089507758),
    zoom: 17,
  );

  static const CameraPosition _initialCameraPosition = CameraPosition(
      bearing: 192.8334901395799,
      target: LatLng(51.917405387278585, -8.397318089507758),
      tilt: 59.440717697143555,
      zoom: 19.151926040649414);

//Launch google maps app
  void launchGoogleMaps() async {
    // Define the latitude and longitude of the desired location
    final double latitude = 51.917405387278585;
    final double longitude = -8.397318089507758;

    final Uri googleMapsUrl = Uri.parse(
        'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$latitude,$longitude');

    _launch(googleMapsUrl);
  }

  Future<void> _launch(Uri url) async {
    if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
      await launchUrl(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch Google Maps';
    }
  }

//**Attempt to open on browser failed on both platforms
  Future<void> openGoogleMapsInBrowser() async {
    final double latitude = 51.917405387278585;
    final double longitude = -8.397318089507758;

    final Uri googleMapsUrl =
        Uri.parse('https://www.google.com/maps?q=$latitude,$longitude');

    if (await canLaunchUrl(googleMapsUrl)) {
      await launchUrl(googleMapsUrl);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch Google Maps in the web browser.';
    }
  }




                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(22.0),
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: launchGoogleMaps,
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: 300,
                        child: GoogleMap(
                          mapType: MapType.hybrid,
                          initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
                          onMapCreated:
                              (GoogleMapController controller) {
                            _controller.complete(controller);

                            // Add the marker to the map when it's created
                            setState(() {
                              _markers.add(
                                Marker(
                                  markerId: MarkerId('your_marker_id'),
                                  position: LatLng(51.917405387278585,
                                      -8.397318089507758),

                                  icon: BitmapDescriptor
                                      .defaultMarkerWithHue(
                                          BitmapDescriptor.hueRed),
                                  // Add other properties as needed
                                ),
                              );
                            });
                          },
                          markers:
                              _markers, // Set the markers on the map
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

I have ensured I have all of the correct import and everything is setup perfectly, what could be causing it to be unclickable on IOS?

Answer (score 0):

To use url_launcher on iOS, open the ios/Runner/Info.plist file and modify it like the below.
Reference: https://dev-yakuza.posstree.com/en/flutter/url_launcher/external_link/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  ...
  <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
  <array>
    <string>https</string>
    <string>http</string>
  </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And then:

```
String query = Uri.encodeComponent(/*your latlong query*/);
Uri appleUrl = Uri.parse('maps:q=$query');
Uri googleUrl = Uri.parse('https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$query');


_launch(appleUrl);
_launch(googleUrl);

 Future<void> _launch(Uri url) async {
   await canLaunchUrl(url)
    ? await launchUrl(url)
    : _showSnackBar('could_not_launch_this_app'.tr());
}
```

Comment: my url_launcher is working I successfully used it elsewhere in the app so this step has already been done

Comment: @youtubeuser1234 Added more code.